# Hive query performance calculation

Tags: performance, validation, mapreduce, hive

I have a need to migrate the data from the traditional EDW to Hive. Post migration of the data, i have to validate if the data is migrated successfully or not i.e. running count queries, min, max etc on the tables that are migrated. Ideally, this is required to be run on the entire data set on both the EDW and Hive for comparison. However, there are few factors that may limit this and the data validation queries can be run only on the subset of the data. This means that sampling is required to choose the representative subset. What tables have to be part of the representative subset is one and the other factor is the sample size itself. Now on determining the sample size, the key aspect is the SLA of the queries. So given the SLA, the number of queries, is it possible to arrive at the sample size? I referred the excel sheet at [link](https://0x0fff.com/hadoop-cluster-sizing/) and arrived at the following formula; This is definitely an approximation only but does this make sense at all?

> **S =  ( ( X * R ) / Q ) * F**
>
> S - Sample Size in GB
>
> X - SLA in minutes * 60
>
> R - Disk Scan Rate of
>   the cluster in GB/sec
>
> Q - Number of queries
>
> F - Adjusting Factor that
>   account for the intermediate data reads (MR), computation within the
>   hive query etc.

Assumption is that the queries are not CPU intensive.

Example: 10 minute SLA, 28 GB/Sec scan rate, 4 queries, F = 0.65

S = ((600 * 28) /4 ) * 0.65 = 2730 GB

Comment: I actually think the the most important factor is the number of machines that can run in parallel. If you take 10% sample, it might take 10% of the time or the exact same time because if you run on all the data - you'll have 10 times more machines running in parallel. So you'd need a sample that fully utilizes your parallelism.

Comment: @Alex L, Yes true and thats why the scan rate is calculated based on the number of available machines

Comment: So Q is the amount of queries that you run in parallel? how do you approximate F?

Comment: Q is the number of queries to be run. May or may not run in parallel. F is an adjusting factor which to me is a trial and error. F should account for various other factors like intermediate data reads, computational time for the hive framework itself; Again this is just an approximation. In fact, it also depends on how the data is spread across nodes. Depending on that it may lead to higher network bandwidth utilization in case of no data locality. I am ok with +- 10% margin of error.